# Repetitive alarm not working in actual devices but working in emulator

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeat

I know this is duplicate question but I have tried all the solution available on the Internet but not able to find the solution.

manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateTables"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

calling this method in `onCreate()` of **mainActivity**.java and I also tried to call the method from application class.

```
private void setTheTimeToUpdateTables(Context context) {

    Log.i("Update table function","Yes");

    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(context,UpdateTables.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    alarmStartTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //midnight
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()>alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis())
    {
        alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }

    Log.i("TIME IS ",Long.toString(alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis()));


    System.out.println("Updating table time "+alarmStartTime);
    System.out.println("Time in millseconds "+alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis());


    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

    Log.d("Alarm","Set for midnight");

}


    public class UpdateTables extends BroadcastReceiver {

        //midnight saga

        DbHelper dbHelper;
        ArrayList<ListMedicine> reminderInfo;
        private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        private static AlarmManager alarmManager;

        private static void init(Context ctx){
            if (alarmManager==null)
                alarmManager=(AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Update tables","yes");   

    }
```

When app is closed than it the updatetables broadcast receiver will not call.

output of ./adb shell dumpsys alarm before the app closed.

```
RTC #5: Alarm{28e47fec type 1 when 1487010660087 user.com.hlthee}
    tag=*alarm*:user.com.hlthee/.UpdateTables
    type=1 whenElapsed=+23h48m35s946ms when=2017-02-14 00:01:00
    window=-1 repeatInterval=86400000 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{24cc8fb5: PendingIntentRecord{19e0864a user.com.hlthee broadcastIntent}}
```

But when the app is closed from recent activity then this entry is also delete. Why?
thats why no alarm is rang when app is closed. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a background service.

Comment: can you give example. @ReazMurshed..

Comment: I think broadcast receiver also do work in background @ReazMurshed. I may be wrong.

Comment: You're registering your broadcast receiver inside an Activity which will be destroyed when the app closes. So you need to register the receiver inside a service and start the service as sticky so that the broadcast can be received. There's a plenty of examples of how a service can be used.

Comment: @ReazMurshed but documentation says The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. Then once i set the alarm then it should rang at specific time. If I use the service it would causes battery and cpu drains and service will be killed by the system.

Answer (score 0):

define a custom action name, such as:

```
public static final String MY_ACTION = "com.sample.myaction"
```

create a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(MY_ACTION)) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

}

Register the receiver on your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.sample.MyAlarmReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.sample.myaction"/>
</intent-filter>
```

setup the alarm, use the following PendingIntent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
```